# Keyboard issues while using BaseInputConnection inside the Custom Webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, inputconnection

I have overridden the onCreateInputConnection inside the Custom WebView class like below

```
class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    public CustomWebView(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context);
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/editor.html")
    }

    public CustomWebView(@Nullable Context context,@Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/editor.html")
    }


    public CustomWebView(@Nullable Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        loadUrl("file:///android_asset/editor.html")
    }
     
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) { 
        // below return statement would be the default implementation
        // return super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs)
        return new BaseInputConnection(this, false);
    }
}
```

Some editable HTML content is loaded into the above Custom Webview, place the below sample editor.html in the asset folder

```
<html> 
<head></head>
<body contenteditable="true">

<h1> this is a sample text </h1></br>
<h2> h2 text</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**Main Issue when BaseInputConnection used in WebView:**
I am not able to perform glide typing or swipe letter typing using the keyboard. This behavior is observed only when BaseInputConnection is used whereas in default implementation glide typing is performed

**Other issues when BaseInputConnection used in WebView**
In some devices like Redmi, the letters are not sent to the Webview while typing using soft keyboard.

I am overriding it to BaseInputConnection because it solves many of my problems in other use-cases. Any help on resolving the keyboard issue would be really appreciated